# Override django admin model saving action

Tags: python, django

I have two django models. If i add an entry via django admin to modelA and I save it, then I would like to add the value of modelB-s total field. (total = total + amount)
Is there a way to override the save method of django admin? Thx for your further answer!

```
class modelA(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class modelB(models.Model):
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**Edit**:
**What I really would like to have is:**

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    transaction_type = (
        (1, "incoming"),
        (2, "outgoing")
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    transfer_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=transaction_type, default=1)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    totalBalance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have a model about employees, who have a totalBalance field, I'm checkin this how much money they have when they want to withdraw for eg.
I have a transaction table, where i record the incoming and outcoming transactions. 
What I would like to have now: 
- when a manager enters an incoming transaction record to Transaction table, 
- then I would like to add this amount at the same time to Employee totalBalance

Comment: It not good to *"define such `sum` fields"*, because it could be very hard to maintain the consistency between the fields.

Comment: Apart from that, you could use the database function [**`Sum(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum) to calculate the sum.

Comment: Let's say, modelA contains withdraw records and modelB contains details of a person, including his total amount of money. So when a withdraw happens, I subtract the person's amount of money as well. How would you do this differently?

Comment: Add a [mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your problem.

Comment: see the example at the edited question